# How to use cookies in saving temporary data in codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, cookies

I'am having problem on how and where i would put my codes in codeigniter. I was new in Php/CI and I was having a hard time with mvc form. I want to put my data's (vaccination record brand) in cookies so that i could store it temporary. I have tried to set my cookies and i got blank result but the data's were inserting in my database. I think i have problem with my controller's code.

my controller's code :

```
function vaccs($id) {
$data['title'] = $this->main_title.' | Vaccination';
$data['jslibraries'] = $this->inc_files->data_tables_scripts();
$data['uid']         = $id;
$data['employee']    = $this->vaccination_model->get_employee($id);
$data['vaccine']    = $this->vaccination_model->get_vaccinationrecord($id,0);
$data['vaccine1']   = $this->vaccination_model->get_vaccinationrecord($id,1); 
$this->load->view('vaccs',$data);

}
```

my view's code:

```
<?php
if (isset($_COOKIE['vaccine'])) {
setcookie('vaccine',$vaccine);
foreach ($_COOKIE[$vaccine] as $vaccine){ ?>

<div class="control-group">
<label class="control-label">
<?php echo '&nbsp'.'<a href="javascript:void(0);"  rel="tooltip"    
title="Delete" onclick="delete_vaccination('.$vaccine->vaccination_record_id.');"><i class="icon-minus-sign"></i></a>'.'';?><?php echo $vaccine->vaccination_record_brand;?>

</label>
</div>
```

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Not a good idea to use PHP native cookies when you have CI to work with. Either use CI sessions or CI cookies instead... (I'd prefer sessions) http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/sessions.html  http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/cookie_helper.html

Comment: You are trying to add an object to your PHP cookie, that won't work like that. Also first you check if there is a cookie named `vaccine` then you're setting it again (to your object value?) then your redefine your `$vaccine` variable/object in the foreach clause?

Comment: @jtheman how could i check if theres a cookie named vaccine? I'm sorry i just read some article and edited some of those code so i'am really having a hard time figuring it out.

Comment: That is what you do in the first line. Then you're messing it up quite badly. What are you trying to do? And what contents is originally in `$vaccine` (brought from the controller model call `$this->vaccination_model->get_vaccinationrecord($id,0);`)?

Comment: yes, $vaccine comes from the model                               $this->vaccination_model->get_vaccinationrecord($id,0);)..i want to store my data in cookie but it goes on my database.

Comment: since you're passing the data into the view with `$data['vaccine']`, you can access it with `$vaccine` in your view.  I definitely would not prefer to use cookies or sessions to pass variables between files in one execution.

Answer (score 0):

You should first load cookie helper.You can load it into autoload file inside config folder
just add `cookie` in helper like this

```
$autoload['helper'] = array('cookie');
```

then you can set the cookie like this

```
<?php
      $name = 'xyz';
      $this->input->set_cookie('cookie_name', $name, 3600*2);
?>
```

then you can get this cookie value by this

```
<?php echo $this->input->cookie('cookie_name');?>
```